# how are read-only fields implemented in React?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I put together this SSCCE to test read-only fields in forms created using ReactJS versus plain HTML forms and fields (also in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mdnzfjja/3/)):

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>comparing ReactJS and simple HTML forms</title>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/react/0.14.0-rc1/react.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/react/0.14.0-rc1/react-dom.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <h3>HTML form</h3>
      <form>
        <input type='text' value='your name'/>
      </form>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h3>form created with ReactJS</h3>
      <div id='reactForm'>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
     var rce = React.createElement.bind(React);

     var SillyReactForm = React.createClass({
       render: function() {
         return rce('form', {}
                  , rce('input', { type: 'text', value:'your name'}));
       }});
     var form = rce(SillyReactForm, {});
     ReactDOM.render(form, document.getElementById('reactForm'));
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Sure enough, the field created with ReactJS is read-only and in fact I see this message in the console as well:

```
Warning: Failed form propType: You provided a `value` prop to a form field without an `onChange` handler. This will render a read-only field. If the field should be mutable use `defaultValue`. Otherwise, set either `onChange` or `readOnly`.
```

My question is how is this enforced by ReactJS as, examining the DOM elements I see no essential difference between the plain HTML form and the ReactJS-generated one:

[image]

Is ReactJS executing some behind-the-scenes JavaScript that sets that field to effectively read-only? And if so, how can I discover this kind of logic that's attached to my DOM elements? Doesn't this run counter to the idea that ReactJS is a library and not a framework (and as such more transparent and easier to reason about?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That warning isn't telling you that React is forcing the input to be readonly.  It's telling you that React isn't.  You'll end up with a mutable input representing immutable state.  The user will be able to make changes to the input, but as soon as a re-render is triggered, those changes will be lost as the input is regenerated from the application state.

That's why React is telling you to add either the `readOnly` or `onChange` attribute.  Either make the input immutable to match up with the state, or make the state mutable to match up with the input.

I haven't used `defaultValue` before, but I imagine it works by automatically hooking up an `onChange` event to some state behind the scenes.  I think React probably also does the same if the `value` attribute is omitted, but does not do this if the `value` field is present, so as not to conflict with any state binding in the component, and instead throws this warning.